# If a set is separable its completion is separable

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

$\tilde{M}$ is the completion of M.

This question has ben done before, but with no answer. My idea is to first: show that $S$,$T$ sets (which compose the separation of M) are actually the preimage of the $S'$,$T'$ sets (which compose a separation in $\tilde{M}$), I've got an isometry to do this but I can't fill the holes:

1)Show that $S'$ and $T'$ are such that $S'\cap T'=\emptyset$.

2)show that the union of $S'$ and $T'$  are equal to $\tilde{M}$

3)Show isometry moves open sets into open sets ( I'm working on this one)

which would complete th demostration

Am i on the right direction? or am I missing a theorem...?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space

The section on completion gives a theorem that might be of use here. Regarding the fact that any function $f:M\rightarrow N$ can be extended to a function $f^{\prime}:\bar{M}\rightarrow N$. Try using a function $f$ which is injective.

Comment: Isn't $\bar{M}$ the _completion_ of $M$?

Comment: i use tilde, because $\overline{M}$ is the closure of M in my lecture notes.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any tildes in this post.

Comment: Maybe some kind of latex problem...I typed:
"\tilde{M} is the separation of M" in the first line

Comment: Indeed that is strange...

Comment: Try \widetilde{M} instead, seems to look better.

Comment: I still think you intended to say completion and not separation on that first line also. Because the separation of a topological space is the pair of disjoint open sets whose union is the whole space.

Comment: Now i noticed waht you mean, now it's right

Comment: The section on Relations with the extension problem here may also be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity

Comment: You seem to be using *separable* to mean *not connected*. If that’s what is meant, the result is simply false. Take $M=\Bbb Q$, $S=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<\sqrt2\}$, and $T=\Bbb Q\setminus S$: $S$ and $T$ form a separation of $Q$, but the completion of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$, which is connected. Unless otherwise defined, *separable* in a topological context means *has a countable dense subset*, and with that meaning of *separable*, the result is true; you need only show that if $D\subseteq M$ is dense in $M$, then $D$ is dense in the completion as well.